# Trouble populating followers of followers in Mongoose schema for MongoDB. How to get desired output?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

this is my `user` Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    photo: {
        type: String,
        default: "https://brighterwriting.com/wp-content/uploads/icon-user-default.png"
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    followers: \[{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "USER"
    }\],

    following: \[{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "USER"
    }],
})
```

Need to populate followers of followers

Attempt:

```
 try {
    const user = await USER.findOne({
        _id: req.user._id
    }).populate({
        path: "followers",
        populate: {
            path: "followers",
            model: "USER"

        }
    })
    console.log(user);
    // The followers field and followers of each follower are now fully populated
} catch (error) {
    // Handle error
}
```

but i am not getting the desired ouput

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("644775fbb1317b2b17bd5e74"),
    photo: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/gurpreetcloud/image/upload/v1682502337/xorxfzc0mq8nxxii9adw.png',
    name: 'me',
    userName: 'me',
    email: 'me@gmail.com',
    password: '$2b$10$GotFQ/3wHCRl0.pJC2pZZuhweY/R9LRXqgJbHF/gNKT0HVsArrpaW',
    followers: [{
        _id: new ObjectId("644e3b2357dd60a2265a902a"),
        photo: 'https://brighterwriting.com/wp-content/uploads/icon-user-default.png',
        name: 'dhoni',
        userName: 'dhoni',
        email: 'dhoni@gmail.com',
        password: '$2b$10$CrJi2XB2hTVWzYLc7hGe.e0sZg9RPbpXGa.nXwf0gOhPkDY8UrDsO',
        followers: [Array],
        following: [Array],
        __v: 0
    }]
}
```